# how to get data between two dates of Last month in YII?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to get data of the last month, i am using the below code to do it, but it is not working correctly for me:

Here is my code:

```
public function getLastMonth($user_id)
{       
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->condition = 'leave_from_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)';
    $criteria->condition = 'leave_to_date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)';
    $criteria->condition = "user_id = $user_id";
    $data = Leaves::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $lastMonthR = 0;
    foreach($data as $lastMonth)
     {
         $lastMonthR += $lastMonth->total_leaves_hours;
     }      
    //return lastMonthR CHtml::encode($lastMonthR);
    return $lastMonthR;
}
```

I want to get the result equivalent to the results of following query that is in MYSQL:

```
SELECT *,sum(total_leaves_hours) FROM tbl_leaves
WHERE leave_from_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND 
leave_to_date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ;
```

When i run the code(shown above) of YII, it shows me all the data of the table, please help me i am new to YII. thanks in advance.

Comment: when you output the SQL in php what do you see? It might being adding OR instead AND.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value for `condition` for the second time you write over the first condition. Combine the two into a single condition. You should also use prepared statements instead of string interpolation:

```
$criteria->condition = 'leave_from_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      AND leave_to_date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND user_id = :id';

$data = Leaves::model()->findAll($criteria, array (':id'=>$user_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `$criteria->condition = ...` three times. That assigns the last value and discards the rest. [Joni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18009929/1233508) gives a simple solution.

However, after looking closer at your logic, it can actually be replaced with a simpler `SUM` query, *if* you do not use any other data from the query. The sample query you gave selects more data, but the function you wrote does not use it - it's not clear if you actually need the records themselves.

```
public function getLastMonth($user_id) {
    $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
      ->select('SUM(total_leaves_hours)')
      ->from(Leaves::model()->tableName())
      ->andWhere('leave_from_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
      ->andWhere('leave_to_date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
      ->andWhere('user_id = :user_id', array(
        ':user_id' => $user_id,
      ))
    ;

    return $cmd->queryScalar();
}
```